# Increase cell value by 1 is increasing by 35

Tags: crash, runtime-error, counting

I'm working on a basic barcode checker that would count the number of correct scans. Starting at zero, every scan should increase by 1, however after the first scan the quantity jumps to 35 and Excel crashes.

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Reset good box
If Range("B15").Cells.Interior.Color = vbGreen Then
Range("B15").Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
End If

'Reset bad box
If Range("F15").Cells.Interior.Color = vbRed Then
Range("F15").Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
End If

'Blanks don't change box color
If Range("B37").Value = "" Then
Range("B37").Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
End If

'Test barcode
If Range("B37").Value = Range("B7").Value Then
Range("B15").Cells.Interior.Color = vbGreen
Else
Range("F15").Cells.Interior.Color = vbRed
End If

*If Range("B37").Value = Range("B7").Value Then
Range("D28").Value = Range("D28").Value + 1
End If
*

End Sub`

I've had this work before, and I have no idea why it's jumping to 35. Could the crash be coming from this being a change event?